# Lazy loading, eager loading or explicit loading in case of multiple joins?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am a beginner to `entity framework`. I have a requirement to fetch many records (sometimes it goes even to millions) from 8 different tables. I am presently joining this tables in `linq` and converting them to `list`. (So i am doing explicit loading here) I know whether eager loading will be more appropriate to use in this case for better performance. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my query:

```
List<FarmerDetailsReport> fdr = 
    (from fp in mstfp join pd in personalDetails on fp.personDetails.Id equals pd.Id
    join ic in identityCertificate on fp.identityCertificate.Id equals ic.Id 
    join pid in pacsInsuranceData on fp.pacsInsuranceData.Id equals pid.Id into temp
    from pid in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join bd in bankDetails on fp.bankDetails.Id equals bd.Id
    join cd in contactDetails on fp.contactDetails.Id equals cd.Id
    join id in incomeDetails on fp.incomeDetails.Id equals id.Id into tmp
    from id in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join ua in user
```

Attributes on `fp.UserId` equals `ua.EmailID`

```
where ((ua.CompanyName == companyName ) && (cd.District == model.DistrictForProfileMIS ) && (cd.Block == model.BlockForProfileMIS) && (bd.bankName == model.BankForProfileMIS ) && Status == "Active")

select new FarmerDetailsReport { .......... }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that a better way than to join lots of tables in that way in entity framework is to create a view in the database (an indexed view) and query that instead. I'm not a database expert, but it should improve performance in the database as well as the code...

And of course you can change the view if the database changes without having to change your code.

Comment: Can i create indexed view using code first in entity framework?

Comment: No, the view you create in the database. It looks like a table to entity framework but can actually be a join of different tables (like in your query).

Answer (score 1):

If performance is critical, I would not use a Linq query. The reason for this, is that you do not know what kind of query EF will create. Yes, EF is quite good in creating efficient queries, but if you have a specific case where performance is critical, doing it yourself (if you are an experienced SQL developer) is still the best option.

So I would create an SP in the database.

### Update

If you want to execute the SP and returns the result in a POCO objects, one good options is to use [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). SP's can be executed very simple:

```
using Dapper;

using (var connection = MyConnectionFactory.GetConnection()) {
    connection.Open();
    var data = cnn.Query<MyPocoObject>(
        "spMySp",
        new { MyParameter = 1 }, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
    );
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Actually my project has implemented entity framework using code first. So wouldn't it be complex to implement SP using code first?

Comment: @Saket Why use entity framework to execute the SP? Just use something else. I'll update my answer with an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework off course you want to use it's possibilities and not go back to Stored Procedures. Use Include Statements (Eager Loading) or Explizit Loading (.Load()) to get your goal. Thats what EF is made for.